# Catching email update errors with Firebase auth (Web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm updating the user's email in Firebase by [re-authenticating him](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#re_authenticate_a_user) and then [updating the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#set_a_users_email_address):

```js
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential('my-email@test.com', 'my-password');

user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
    .then(user.updateEmail('my-new-email@test.com'))
    .then(() => {
      console.log('ok');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        // ...
      } else if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
        // ...
      } else if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        // ...
      }
    });
```

It works, but I can't catch the errors thrown by the `user.updateEmail` part. For some reasons the errors from the `user.reauthenticateWithCredential` part are caugth. For example, if I enter a wrong password I have an error with the code `auth/wrong-password` code in my `catch((error) => {}` block, but if I enter an invalid email, I only have this message in the console:

```
Uncaught 
L {code: "auth/invalid-email", message: "The email address is badly formatted."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nervermind I'm an idiot:

```
.then(user.updateEmail('my-new-email@test.com'))
```

should be

```
.then(() => user.updateEmail('my-new-email@test.com'))
```